# how to set a fields value to equal another fields value in infopath Form?

Tags: infopath, infopath-rules

I'm setting up a calculated field and I need to display a value from another field based on another field's entry. Example:

```
If EventType equals "Down Time", set calculated field value to equal the value in the EventTime field.

If EventType equals "Slow Time", set calculated field to default formula.
```

How on earth do I do this?

Comment: Hi @Carl, are you checked the below answer ? are you still need further information?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In InfoPath, you should be aware of you can't set the `calculated field` directly through the rule. and to achieve that as a workaround,  you should do the following:

- Add a new text field to your form > rename it as you need (`field1`).
- In calculated field > specify its data source to be this field `field1` by right click > select properties > specify the data source.
- Now click on your `EventType` field > from the above ribbon > properties tab > add a rule `on This Field Change` > `Set A field Value`.

[image]

- At set **Field** value, select the field that you have already inserted (`field1`).
- At the **Value** > click on function column > select `EventTime` field as shown below.

[image]

- Now the value of `field1` should be the value of `EventTime` when the `EventType` is changed. Meanwhile, the `calculated field` data source is `field1`.so the `calculated field` = `field1`.
- the last thing, to make `field1` hidden, just remove it from form, but it will be there in fields list at Main data connection.